# Spring Data: How to get the same entities by ID

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

How can I make Spring Data return same entities by ID every time findById(id) is called?
If I invoke this twice I'll get two equal objects, but now the same one, so actions I perform to one of these, doesn't affect the other one.

```
obj1 = objectRepo.findById("testID").orElse(null);
obj2 = objectRepo.findById("testID").orElse(null);
obj1.setX("Y");
System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2)); //false
```

Is it possible to do just in configuration files?
I'm using Spring 5.0.0 with Spring Data MongoDB 2.0.0.M7

Comment: have you overridden the equals method for the Class corresponding to `obj`? if not only objects that have same reference will be equal. In this case, spring creates new objects for each query, even though object contents match.

Comment: Yes, it's overridden, return this.x.equals(other.x)  
But I need obj1 and obj2 to be the same object, obj1==obj2 (same links)

Comment: you cannot achieve obj1==obj2 as spring instantiates these objects when you do the query. Separate instantiation, different reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to have some sorts of **caching**.

Follow this article to cache **MondoDB** with **Redis**
 [Caching in MongoDB With Redis Using Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/enabling-caching-in-mongodb-database-with-redis-us)

The architecture is as follows

- For find, operation if the entity is int the cache return it.
- Else fetch the object from db. Put it in the cache and return.
- For Every update invalidate the cache entry or update it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not updated for both objects. The actual scenario work like this:[image]